# How do you add a value to a cell instead of removing the value that already exists in the cell?

Tags: c#, excel

How to add a value to a cell in an excell sheet instead of removing the value that exists? i know how to start up excel and how to write to cells but this will overwrite the already existin value how to add a value instead? in code

Comment: `cell.Value = cell.Value + someValue;`?

Comment: testing not sure if this will work

Comment: if you dont want to overwrite the already existing value then where do you intend to store the result?... In code you can store the result in a variable and then as suggested by @shahkalpesh it will be like variable value = cell.value + somevalue

Comment: @shahkalpesh answer was correct